# Haskell conversion to a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am just staring with Haskell!!!
Assume I have a function that recursively calls itself to generate a series

Assume a simple example of sum:

```
func n | n==0 = 0
       | n==1 = 1
       | otherwise = func(n-1) + func(n)
```

So if I call sum 3, it outputs the value 6.

How would I be able to generate a list [1,2,3] if sum 3 is called instead of giving the final output. I need to carry out list operations

When I write the following, I get an error-- parse error on input |

```
toList n | n >0 = let funcList = map func [0..]
```

Comment: Functions in Haskell don't need parenthesis when invoking, and this function will not complete for `func 3`, because it will recursively invoke itself because of the `func(n)` at the end.

Comment: Try this to see if it is what you want: `toList n = map func [1..n]`

Comment: `otherwise = func(n-1) + func(n)` will recur forever with no result. You mean `otherwise = func(n-1) + func(n-2)` for the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
funcList = map func [0..]
```

So now `funcList !! n` will have the same value as `func n`, i.e. it is as if you wrote:

```
funcList = [ func 0, func 1, func 2, func 3, ...]
```

Comment: does this mean the list is stored in a variable funcList?

Comment: I edited my question for the silly error that I just dont understand. Why would it raise such an error?